# Expo, React Native Firebase: GoogleSignIn.initAsync(): undefined is not an object

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, react-native-firebase

I did all of these as said in the [docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google-sign-in/)

1   Go to your app.json and make sure you define your ios.bundleIdentifier and the android.package you want to use.

2   Open up the Firebase Console and setup a new project, or use an existing one.

3   Create a native iOS, and Android app using the Bundle ID and Android package you defined earlier.

4   Download the GoogleService-info.plist (iOS) & the google-services.json (Android). Move them to your Expo project.

5   In the app.json, set your expo.ios.config.googleSignIn.reservedClientId to the value of REVERSE_CLIENT_ID in the GoogleService-info.plist.

6   Also in app.json, set expo.android.googleServicesFile to the relative path of your google-services.json. Make sure the file is located somewhere in your Expo project.

My sign in screen:

```
import { GoogleSignIn } from 'expo-google-sign-in';

export default class SignIn extends React.Component {
  state = { user: null };


  componentDidMount() {
    this.initAsync();
  }

  initAsync = async () => {
    try {
      await GoogleSignIn.initAsync({ clientId: '{client id from the file here}' });
} catch ({ message }) {
  alert('GoogleSignIn.initAsync(): ' + message);
  console.log(message);
}

    this._syncUserWithStateAsync();
  };

  _syncUserWithStateAsync = async () => {
    const user = await GoogleSignIn.signInSilentlyAsync();
    this.setState({ user });
  };

signOutAsync = async () => {
    await GoogleSignIn.signOutAsync();
    this.setState({ user: null });
  };

  signInAsync = async () => {
    try {
      await GoogleSignIn.askForPlayServicesAsync();
      const { type, user } = await GoogleSignIn.signInAsync();
      if (type === 'success') {
        this._syncUserWithStateAsync();
      }
    } catch ({ message }) {
      alert('login: Error: ' + message);
    }
  };

  onPress = () => {
    if (this.state.user) {
       this.signOutAsync();
    } else {
      this.signInAsync();
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>            
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPress}>
            <View style={styles.googleSignInButton}>
               <AntDesign name='google' size={32} style={styles.googleIcon} />
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign In using Google</Text>
             </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

I get this error

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoGoogleSignIn.GoogleSignIn.initAsync')
```

For some reason I don't know, GoogleSignIn object is returned undefined.

Help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found this solution on the [expo forum](https://forums.expo.io/t/expo-google-sign-in-doesnt-seem-to-work/20231/16) which worked for me. Change

```js
import GoogleSignIn from ‘expo-google-sign-in’;
```

To:

```js
import * as GoogleSignIn from ‘expo-google-sign-in’;
```

Comment: I did as your said, I got this error: 
    **expo-google-sign-in is not supported in the Expo Client because a custom URL scheme is required at build time. Please refer to the docs for usage outside of Expo www.npmjs.com/package/expo-google-sign-in**

Comment: I'm still working on that part :-) If you manage to solve, please post here.